# Could not find artifact org.scalatest:maven-scalatest-plugin:jar:1.0

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, scalatest

I'm trying to run some scala tests (FlatSpec style) using maven, however, when I run `mvn test` I get the following error.

> Could not find artifact org.scalatest:maven-scalatest-plugin:jar:1.0

I'm following the instructions from https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest-maven-plugin and http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin. I noticed that the last update to this git repository was 2 years ago. Is this plugin still the de facto standard way to run scala tests from maven?

From this site, http://ladstatt.blogspot.com/2012/06/testing-with-maven-scaladin-scalatest.html, it says to add a pluginRepository, but that doesn't help as the error still shows.

I'm using Scala v2.10.6 and Maven 3.3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link shows that plugin should be of version `1.0-SNAPSHOT`. And indeed, you can see here: `https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/scalatest/maven-scalatest-plugin/` that there is only that version. So check you plugin declaration in `pom.xml`. It should contain `<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>` and not `1.0`

Comment: I changed the version per your advise. It is getting further than previously. However, now I get this message: `Exception in thread "ScalaTest-main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ERROR: -p has been deprecated for a very long time and is no longer supported, to prepare for reusing it for a different purpose in the near future. Please change all uses of -p to -R`

this happens at `org.scalatest.tools.ArgsParser$.checkArgsForValidity(ArgsParser.scala:51)`

any ideas?

Comment: nvm, I downgraded from `org.scalatest:scalatest_2.10:3.0.0-M15` to `org.scalatest:scalatest_2.10:2.0.M6-SNAP8` and everything works now. I'm going to try to increment that version slowly and see what happens.